# Stop Handler in service Android

Tags: android, kotlin, service, handler, runnable

I have been using handler inside service class, the handler is responsible for sending location every 5 seconds via socket. When logging out, the service gets stopped but the handler still running.
I tried every possible way, By using any boolean variable is not feasible in my case because i have to start again that handler.

```
public Runnable mn_Runnable12 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gps = new GPSTracker(LocationService.this);
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                latString = Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()); // Live
                logString = Double.toString(gps.getLongitude());
                connection= MyApplication.getInstance().getConnection();
                if (connection!=null&&connection.isConnected()) {
                    sendLocation();
                }

            }
        }
    };
```

this is inside `onCreate()` of service.

```
 T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {
                                      mHandler12.postDelayed(mn_Runnable12, 5000);
                                  }
                              },
                5000,
                5000);
```

I try to stop the handler in `onDestroy` method of service, service gets topped but the handler still running.

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        System.out.println("Location Service Detaroy-----");
        if (connection.isConnected()) {
            unSubscribe();
        }
        mHandler12.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        mHandler10.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that you still have calls running in `sendLocation()` by the time you stop your `Handler`. In `onDestroy()` set a boolean to true and in `sendLocation()` only continue if that boolean is true.

Comment: @HB I tried to set bool value but in my case, this way is not feasible because after login I have to start again with a new socket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Also have to cancel `Timer` Since its running repeatedly with an interval.
First cancel timer and then remove handlers callback.

```
  T.cancel();
  T.purge();
  // remove handler here
```

Comment: Timer doesn't get started when the app comes from background?

Comment: That's probably because of oncreate not getting called again . You have to create and cancle timer in specifi lifecycle methods. I am not sure what kind of service you are running that's why I can not comment on that .

Comment: `LocationService extends Service ` using this, timer ` T.scheduleAtFixedRate` is being called inside in `onCreate' should I instantiate again timer in `onCreate`

Comment: is there any way to start the timer again?

Comment: If you stop Service on logout `onDestroy` will get called . and when you start it again `onCreate` will get called so timer should get Started automatically . Isn't that the case is `onCreate` is not getting called on starting service second time ?

Comment: my service still running in the background but timer gets stopped after some second when app goes to backgound.

Comment: after  remove `T.cancel()` `T. purge() , timer keeps sending location when app is in backgound.